# Leaflet.js with OneMap: Marker and Polygon Issue

Tags: javascript, leaflet, sapui5

I am using [onemap leaflet](https://cdn.onemap.sg/leaflet/onemap-leaflet.js) library to use `leaflet.js` with `onemap`

I am able to plot `Singapore map` in a SAPUI5 flexbox control. However, marker and polygon are not visible on the map. There is no error while adding a polygon but it does not appear on map. I have used following code to add polygon:

```
var latlngs = [
    [103.908057506263, 1.30981613450459],
    [103.908215431086, 1.30910851741726],
    [103.908429273653, 1.30850269384475],
    [103.908535156551, 1.30825745789562]
];
var polygon = L.polygon(latlngs, {
    color: 'red'
});

polygon.addTo(map);
```

While adding a marker, I am getting following error:

> Couldn't autodetect L.Icon.Default.imagePath, set it manually.

I need to draw polygon and show some markers.
Please help.

Comment: Please separate your question into independent issues. As for the Marker issue, you should probably add more details as well.

Comment: The polygon issue is the usual ["latlng vs lnglat" confusion](https://macwright.org/lonlat/).

Comment: Did you manage to figure out the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the marker images default path using:

```
L.Icon.Default.imagePath = './images'
```

This will point to the correct folder for default markers.